# how to connect parse database and xamarin

Tags: xamarin

whan i want to make a test connnection between parse and xamarin i got this error (Error: Build failed. See the build log for details. (ParseAndroidStarterProject))

and this is my code

```
using System;
using Android.App;
using Android.Runtime;
using Parse;

namespace ParseAndroidStarterProject
{
[Application]
public class App : Application
{
    public App (IntPtr javaReference, JniHandleOwnership transfer) :            base(javaReference, transfer)
    {
    }
    /*
      public  async override  void ViewDidLoad(){
        var testObject = new ParseObject ("TestObject");
        testObject ["foo"] = "bar";
        await testObject.SaveAsync ();
    }
    */
    public async  override void OnCreate ()
    {
        base.OnCreate ();
        var testObject = new ParseObject ("TestObject");
        testObject ["foo"] = "bar";
        await testObject.SaveAsync ();
        // Initialize the parse client with your Application ID and .NET Key found on
        // your Parse dashboard
        ParseClient.Initialize("gBwRzJNUJ7jwhzf9Yen8qoVvFAEEwvrgWk3pqFSK",
            "FGgf0xrE78zAssgxT7jiMFtLdcBdOpNiCsjHQosq");
    }
}
```

}

i follow all the steps in https://www.parse.com/apps/quickstart#parse_data/mobile/android/xamarin/new

i try to use another code just for check if the compilation works well and it does

any help ?

Comment: what does the build log say?

Comment: (Error: Build failed. See the build log for details. (ParseAndroidStarterProject))

Comment: I think @Jason referred to the details from the build log...